# How to get Twitter Bootstrap with Spring Roo?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-roo

I am developing a web application using Spring Roo as a project for my uni subject. I have created all the entities, controllers, views and everything else. But now I would like to basically ignore all the tagx, jspx files created by Roo and create my own views using Twitter Bootstrap. I am new to web development and basically I don't know even where to start. What do I have to do to start using the twitter bootstrap css files, where do I put the downloaded files, how do I include them?? I am so confused, help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 4):

You can start with **RooStrap** by Bhagya Silva as your template.[1](http://www.dzone.com/links/roostrap_introduced_brings_the_best_of_both_world.html) I created it as a Spring Roo project with enough customizations done so you can simply start with Twitter Bootstrap and Spring Roo. =) If you do any further enhancements to the base templates, feel free to fork the project, do the changes and send up a pull request on GitHub and I'll be more than happy to incorporate them in the next revisions of RooStrap.

You can find RooStrap from the following location on GitHub.

http://bhagyas.github.com/roostrap/

Cheers and all the best with RooStrap, Spring Roo and Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Note by using gvNIX 1.3.1 your project will be improved with both **Bootstrap** and **Dandelion Datatables**.

Take a look at https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app

Answer (score 1):

There's also a proper plugin at http://github.com/killersite/roo-twitter-bootstrap. Yuo ca use it this way:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.lrkwz.roostrap --projectName roostrap --java 6 --packaging JAR
persistence setup --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT --provider HIBERNATE 
entity jpa --class com.lrkwz.roostrap.domain.Person 
field string --fieldName personName --sizeMin 2
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Country
field string --fieldName countryName --notNull
osgi start --url file:///home/lrkwz/roo-twitter-bootstrap/target/com.ct.roo.addon.tbootstrap-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
web mvc setup
web mvc install bootstrap
web mvc all --package com.lrkwz.roostrap.web
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I have my SpringRoo projects already created I cannot use roostrap as my template. That is what I did for integrate this awesome theme in my projects:

1. Copy directory *bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-resources* to *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/resources/META-INF/*
2. Copy file *bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/webapp/styles/roostrap.css* to *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/styles*
3. Copy *file bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/roostrap.properties* to *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes*
4. Delete directory *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags* and copy directory *bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags* to *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF*
5. Overwrite file *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx* with *bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx*
6. Overwrite file *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jspx* with *bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/index.jspx*
7. I dont like generate's SpringRoo menu in my projects, so my *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml* looks like:

   ```
   <definition name="default" template="/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx">
       <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/header.jspx" />
       <!-- 
       <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx" />
       -->
       <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx" />
   </definition>
   ```
8. Overwrite file *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx* with *bhagyas-roostrap-2f4ac0d/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/default.jspx*. If you did the step 7 go to *default.jspx* and look for `<div class="container">`, it has to looks like this:

   ```
       <div class="container">

           <div class="row">
               <!--  
               <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="sidebar-nav">
                       <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" ignore="true" />
                   </div>

               </div>
                -->


               <div class="col-md-12 panel panel-default">
                   <div id="main" class="panel-body">
                       <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/> 
                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>

       </div>
   ```
9. Modify file *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml* and look for:

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>
   ```

   and change default theme from standard to roostrap:

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver" id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="roostrap"/>
   ```
10. Modify file *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx* and add `class="container"` to the main div. Like this:

    ```
    <div class="container" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" id="footer" version="2.0">
    ```
11. Add to the file *YOUR_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/i18n/messages.properties*

    ```
    global_theme_roostrap=roostrap 
    welcome_text_roostrap=bla bla bla
    welcome_quote=bla bla bla
    welcome_quote_author=bla bla bla
    ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in use **Bootstrap** on your **ROO** projects, you can try using the new **gvNIX-1.3.1-RELEASE** version and using this simple command:

> web mvc bootstrap setup

Here you can found some examples about an Spring Roo application using Bootstrap appearance:

[https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app#result](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-app)

If you are intereseted on gvNIX project, you can find more info at:

https://code.google.com/p/gvnix/

https://github.com/DISID/gvnix